# Create a table using data from another's table column that is in JSON form

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I'm using a Postgres server. Here's how my table looks

[image: Here's how my table looks like.]

which means the column of the genres of each movie is in form:

```
[
    {'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'},
    {'id': 36, 'name': 'History'},
    {'id': 10749, 'name': 'Romance'}
]
```

As you can see the genres for each movie are in a `VARCHAR` variable and in JSON array.

What I want to do is unpack the contents of the JSON and create a new table named `Genres`, which is going to have every genre once with its unique id.

So for the upper example I want my new table to look like this:

```
id  | genre
18  | 'Drama'
36  | 'History'.
```

How can I do that?

Comment: If you are using Postgres why have you tagged SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

You should definitly fix your schema, and store your JSON data as `JSON[B]`  datatype rather than as strings.

That said, one option is to force the conversion to json so we then can use Postsgres' powerful json functions to unnest the arrays and access the inner objects. As far as your data shows, you just need to turn the single quotes to double quotes to make the strings valid Postgres JSON, so this should work:

```
insert into genres(id, genre)
select distinct js ->> 'id', js ->> 'name'
from mytable t
cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements( (replace(genres, ''', '"'))::jsonb ) j(js)
```